# Dockerizing KONG to run in a automated fashion and Setting the upstream urls dynamically

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, yaml, kong

I am trying to write a yaml file for dockerizing KONG. The requirement to set up KONG is basic in which I want to set up two up stream urls (when the respective request comes, it point to these urls). 
The YAML file I created is :

```
version: "2"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    container_name: kong-database
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=kong
      - POSTGRES_DB=kong
web:
    image: kong:0.12-alpine
    container_name: kong
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN_SSL=0.0.0.0:8444  
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8444:8444"
    links:
      - kong-database:kong-database
 kong:
    admin_host: 192.168.99.100:8001
    apis:
      - name:onboarding-api
        host:
          - eso.com.onboarding
        upstream_url: http://192.168.99.100:8080
        - name:orchestrationcockpit-api
        host:
          - eso.com.orchestrationcockpit
        upstream_url: http://192.168.99.100:808
```

which is based on setting up KONG docker commands :

```
 1) run Kong in Docker:
docker run -d --name kong-database \
-p 5432:5432 \
-e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
-e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
postgres:9.4

docker run --rm \
--link kong-database:kong-database \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
kong:0.12-alpine kong migrations up

docker run -it --name kong \
--link kong-database:kong-database \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN_SSL=0.0.0.0:8444" \
-p 8000:8000 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-p 8001:8001 \
-p 8444:8444 \
kong:0.12-alpine

2) Run the attached docker-compose.yml files to start Onboarding and OrchestrationCockpit containers (these should be built first by runnning mvn clean install in the repositories. Then verify that the services are running o:

curl -i -X GET \
--url http://192.168.99.100:8080/onboarding/v1

curl -i -X GET \
--url http://192.168.99.100:8081/orchestrationcockpit/v1

3) Add the services to the Kong access gateway
curl -i -X POST \
--url http://192.168.99.100:8001/apis/ \
--data 'name=onboarding-api' \
--data 'hosts=eso.com.onboarding' \
--data 'upstream_url=http://192.168.99.100:8080'

curl -i -X POST \
--url http://192.168.99.100:8001/apis/ \
--data 'name=orchestrationcockpit-api' \
--data 'hosts=eso.com.orchestrationcockpit' \
--data 'upstream_url=http://192.168.99.100:8081'

curl -i http://192.168.99.100:8001/apis/

4) Verify that the services can be accessed from the gateway:
curl -i -X GET \
--url http://192.168.99.100:8000/onboarding/v1 \
--header 'Host: eso.com.onboarding'

curl -i -X GET \
--url http://192.168.99.100:8000/orchestrationcockpit/v1 \
--header 'Host: eso.com.orchestration'
```

Am i doing it right? Moreover, if I am not aware of the upstream urls how can I set them dynamically? i.e when the KONG is to be setup in production environment I need to change the IP addresses, is there a better way of doing this without hard coding of the IP addresses?

**Error**: The addition of APIs and upstream URl is not correct. What would be the correct way to add upstream url for KONG using YAML? OS used: Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to set up routes in Kong via docker-compose directly.

You could, however, create a container and run a script in there which executes the `curl` commands in a script.

Comment: Thank you Joachim. I have found a way to do this and what you suggest is correct. Had to create my own container to override their functionality solely because the 'migration up ' commands needs to run before the curl commands can run to add upstream urls.